# How to increase session time out for 1 days in asp.net mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

Hi i have create one project in the asp.net mvc c#.and i have create one login module and one is list of the user show after login in the project. i have do in login time i have set Userid and username set in the session. and after login successfully check session userid on user page and then after i have show user list.but i am after login my project run on browser and idea stay for the 5 mint and i am reload user list then automatically my session is null and i am redirect on login page. i want to session etlish for the 1 days store.

This is my set session value login time =>

```
Session["UserId"] = UserId;
Session["UserName"] = UserName;
```

i have try like this in web.config file set sessiontime out for the 1 days =>

```
<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="52428800" />
<trust level="Full" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
 <sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

this is type i have try but not getting success and my session automatically null after 5 mint in ideal mode. any one now where is problem in the code.

Comment: Also check IIS settings, detailed here (second answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912862/asp-net-why-are-sessions-timing-out-sessionstate-timeout-set

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi but this problem  i am facing on my local pc.

Comment: You are still using IIS Express, even on local machine. You can check if it is running.